# How to call a class in the done() method of a class which extends Swingworker?

Tags: java, object, call, swingworker, cd

I've written a class which opens cd/dvd (named Cdopener) and I have another class (named Burn) which extends Swingworker and it does something in the done() method of it, I want to make an object of class Cdopener so that it opens the cd when Burn class runs.

it is my Cdopener class:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Cdopener {
    public Cdopener() {
        try {
            //********Start VBScript code to open cd tray************
            String a = "Set oWMP = CreateObject(\"WMPlayer.OCX\")" + "\n" 
                + "Set colCDROMs = oWMP.cdromCollection" + "\n" 
                + "For d = 0 to colCDROMs.Count - 1" + "\n" 
                + "colCDROMs.Item(d).Eject" + "\n" 
                + "Next" + "\n" 
                + "set owmp = nothing" + "\n" 
                + "set colCDROMs = nothing" + "\n" 
                + "wscript.Quit(0)";
            //********End VBScript code to open cd tray************

            //Create a vbscript file called OpenCdTray.vbs
            File myCdTrayOpener = new File("OpenCdTray.vbs");

            //Create a PrintWriter object that will use to write into created file
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(myCdTrayOpener);

            //Write all string in (a) into created file
            System.out.println(a);
            pw.print(a);

            //Flush all resource in PrintWriter to make sure
            //there are no data left in this stream.
            pw.flush();

            //Close PrintWriter and releases any
            //system resources associated with it
            pw.close();

            //Create a Desktop object to open created vbs file(OpenCdTray.vbs).
            //It will open using default application that will use
            //to handle this file in targeted computer.
            //True application to run this file is wscript.exe
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(myCdTrayOpener);

            //Delete created vbs file before terminate application
            myCdTrayOpener.deleteOnExit();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And it's the method done() of Burn class:

```
protected void done() {

    taskProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);

    if (this.error.length() == 0) {
        taskProgressBar.setValue(100);
        taskProgressBar.setString("Done");
    }

    // this.resultLbl.getText() +"\n"+getUserName();
    addLog(resultLbl.getText());
    // super.done();
}
```

I want to call Cdopener so that it opens the cd, for doing that I simply added this part to my code to make an object of Cdopener in the done() part of Burn class:

```
Cdopener cdopener = new Cdopener();
```

but it seems something should change because it doesn't open the cd in this way! How should I call the class Cdopener in my done method?

Comment: Well for a start, I wouldn't have all that code in the *constructor* of `Cdopener` (and I'd name it differently, but that's a different matter). Have you debugged into the code to see what happens? Perhaps an exception is being thrown?

Comment: No there is no problem to have all that code in the constructor, I've debugged it and even I have made an object of it in the main of another class which doesn't extends Swingworker and it has worked and opens the cd, the problem is when I want to call it from the done method of a class which extends Swingworker. @JonSkeet

Comment: "No there is no problem to have all that code in the constructor" - There is in that it's ugly design. I'm not saying it can't work, just that it's not clean code. You still haven't said what you've observed when debugging *in the context that it's causing a problem* though.

Comment: when debugging when it arrives at Burn.execute() and i press f8 to step into, it works and opens the cd but when i run the program it doesn't do any thing!! @JonSkeet

Comment: So it works when running under the debugger, but not when running without the debugger? Does it work if you're running under the debugger but not stepping through? (All this information should be in the question, btw...)

Comment: it doesn't work when running under the debugger but not stepping through @JonSkeet

Comment: Okay, so next you add logging to see exactly how far it gets, etc... normal diagnostics, basically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(myCdTrayOpener.getAbsolutePath()));
for opening you vbs file to ensure that it is pointing to the right file directory.

Comment: try removing the myCdTrayOpener.deleteOnExit(); and add System.out.print(myCdTrayOpener.getAbsolutePath()) and check for the actual file it it is created

Comment: again nothing changes.